# Does String.Format have a bug?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

**When I use a custom formatter and pass `{{{0:,;'{{0}}'}}}` to `String.Format`, it passes my formatter `,;'{{0}}'}`**

**Why is there a trailing brace? Is it my problem or `String.Format`'s?**

---

I wrote an IFormatProvider/ICustomFormatter that joins IEnumerables. It splits the passed format string (once) on ';' and uses the first part as the join string and the second part as a format string for the elements. For instance,

```
{0:,;'{{0}}'}
```

would result in the formatter being passed `,;'{0}'`, which it would break into `,` and `'{0}'` as the join and element format strings, respectively. It would then return

```
String.Join(",", arr.Select((elem, index) => String.Format("'{0}'", elem, index))
```

When I use

```
({0:,;'{{0}}'})
```

as my format string, I get

```
('elem0','elem1', ... )
```

as I would expect. This error only occurs when I try to use braces instead of parenthesis.

---

**Code suitable for LINQPad:**

```
void Main()
{
    // works
    String.Format(new JoinFormatter(), "({0:, ;'{{0}}'})", (object)new[] { "a", "b", "c" }).Dump();

    // doesn't work
    String.Format(new JoinFormatter(), "{{{0:, ;'{{0}}'}}})", (object)new[] { "a", "b", "c" }).Dump();
}

public class JoinFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public ICustomFormatter Other;

    public object GetFormat(Type service)
    {
        if (service == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (arg == null || format == null)
            if (Other == null)
                return String.Format("{0}", arg);
            else
                return Other.Format(format, arg, provider);

        if (arg is string || !(arg is IEnumerable))
            if (Other != null)
                return Other.Format(format, arg, provider);
            else if (arg is IFormattable)
                return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, provider);
            else
                return arg.ToString();

        string join, elemf;
        var index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            index = format.IndexOf(';', index);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                join = format;
                elemf = null;
                break;
            }

            if (index == 0)
            {
                join = "";
                elemf = format.Substring(1);
                break;
            }

            if (index == format.Length - 1)
            {
                join = format.Substring(0, format.Length - 1);
                elemf = null;
                break;
            }

            if (index > 0 && format[index - 1] == '!')
                if (index > 1 && format[index - 2] == '!')
                {
                    join = format.Substring(0, index - 1);
                    elemf = format.Substring(index + 1);
                }
                else
                    continue;

            join = format.Substring(0, index);
            elemf = format.Substring(index + 1);
            break;
        }


        return String.Join(join, ((IEnumerable)arg).Cast<object>().Select((o, i) => elemf == null ? o.ToString() : String.Format(provider, elemf, o, i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: it is hard to understand the issue, can you provide the full code instead of snippet? can you provide a working example in one block of code?

Comment: Agreed, although I strongly suspect we can answer the title with "No, your code has a bug." Any reason you're not just using a JSON API to do this properly?

Comment: Originally I wrote the formatter because I was tired of writing `"(" + String.Join(", ", arr.Select( ... )) + ")"`, etc constantly, so I made a general solution. Currently, I'm not using a JSON API because it would be overkill. I guess I could easily use `ToDictionary`, etc, but now that I've found this bug I'd like to squash it.

Comment: Figured it out. Now I have to find a workaround.

Comment: @FireLizzard so does that mean in conclusion there is no bug?

Comment: And it still leaves the open question of why you're formatting JSON yourself instead of using Json.NET or something similar.

Comment: Because it seems excessive to use Json.NET to create a flat object of `prop: null`

Comment: @DavidL, there is no bug.

Comment: @FireLizzard, i would suggest that you delete this question in that case.

Comment: It may be useful to anyone else confused as to why their custom formatter isn't working as expected.

Comment: Overkill to use provided, tested, proven JSON library - not overkill to write own formatter?

Comment: I didn't write the formatter for that purpose. It was something I already had around. And yes, JSON.Net is overkill when I could get the same result with `"{" + String.Join(",", arr.Select(e => String.Format("'{0}':null", e))) +"}"`. Which is almost exactly what my formatter does.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve my intended result, I used `{{ {0:,;'{{0}}'} }}` instead. Adding spaces got `String.Format` to interpret the string the way I wanted it to. With `{{{<ArgNum>:<FormatStr>}}}`, it is interpreting the first two right braces as part of `FormatStr` and the last right brace as terminating the argument format specifier. Whereas I want the first right brace to terminate the argument format specifier and I want the last two right braces to append a right brace to the output.